# Grails 3 scaffolding issue

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I'm trying to port my project from Grails 2.4 to 3.0. Nothing fancy: 12 Domains, 13 Controllers and a service.
Everything works fine, except when I try to include the Scaffolding plugin. I literally follow the manual [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/scaffolding.html), but the syntax must be wrong. Adding the plugin line as specified:

```
    plugins {
        …
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.0"
        …
    }
```

leads to this:

```
    BUILD FAILED                

Total time: 1.559 secs      
| Error Error initializing classpath: startup failed:
build file 'E:\GrailsIdeaProjects\HcaServer\build.gradle': 17: only id(String) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block

See http://gradle.org/docs/2.3/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block for information on the plugins {} block

 @ line 17, column 5.
       compile ":scaffolding:2.0.0"
       ^

1 error
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Somebody knows the right syntax to include the Scaffolding plugin in Grails 3?

EDIT: Thanks to Casey for pointing me in the right direction: Scaffolding plugin is actually already included in default build.gradle. Anyway, i still get a webpage like this on every controller:

```
Error: Page Not Found (404)
Path: /*controllerName*/index
```

I've been using the same syntax as per the manual, declaring a `static scaffold = true` on each controller. Why do I get a 404 page then? I do have index.gsp, error.gsp and notFound.gsp in my views folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching for a while, turns out dynamic scaffolding hasn't made it yet into Grails 3:
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/grails-dev-discuss/6R2YaF96Uts

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that documentation hasn't been updated for Grails 3.0 yet. Your `build.gradle` file should have a `dependencies` block, where you can specify the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
}
```

You can also see this by creating a new app using Grails 3.0 and checking out the default `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works for me.

```
dependencies {
compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
}
```

I am using grails 3.09.